# How to change the audio output speed while the audio is playing in Python

Tags: python, audio-streaming

I was wondering if anyone knew how to change the speed that an audio is playing while the audio is playing. For example, changing the playback speed to x2 while watching a video. I'm hoping to be able to do this without making the sound choppy. Any ideas?